# Run business logic using scripting language

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, architecture, java-7

We have a web application in which the web pages are built dynamically. Dynamically meaning, the whole UI is stored as JSON in the back-end and the front-end draws the UI accordingly. There are use-cases where the data collection happens across multiple forms. The order in which the forms are displayed depends on the data entered in previous forms.

e.g. Assume the user is viewing `form1` and there could be a business logic like if `age > 25` show `form2` else `form3`

This is a simple example but it could get much much more complicated. And the logic differs across the clients. This business logic could also be developed by third party developers.

`javascript` is one of the options to store this business logic. But, the application is being built in Java7 and deployed in Google App Engine. Performance and Security are the important criteria to decide the approach. Following are the approaches that we have considered as of now:

- Have a separate `NodeJS` application and make an API call to execute the business logic
- Run Javascript in JavaScript Script Engine which is part of JDK 7

Could you suggest what are the best approaches to executing `javascript` in a Java application?

Answer (score 0):

Rhino is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely in Java. It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide scripting to end users.
Here is a link - http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

Answer (score 0):

Given the global nature of Javascript and the fact that the specific logic you're referring to, I tend to agree with Alex about JS. That said there are complaints about Rhino's performance so I wouldn't recommend that right off. Unless the performance proves horrible for your use case, I'd recommend using the built-in to start out. Then as you know more about your use-case, and specific performance profile, you can shift to a better solution if needed.

Here are some additional thoughts to help you frame the question:

1. You should run any scripting interpreter open to 3rd parties with a babysitter thread. (i.e., kill them after certain amount of resources consumed--that's not what babysitters should do, but alas...). Any complete scripting language can do a simple "while(true): wait()"
2. Unless the complexity of the logic is massive (i.e., you said one or two if-then's in your example; this can be handled by any language) language isn't a function of security or performance, but one of comfort and familiarity with those using it--i.e., JavaScript should be easy. If your customization team knows python, then go ahead and use an embedded jython, etc.
3. I wouldn't spin up separate services for simple customization. Again unless the complexity is massive, an embedded engine would be preferred. Spinning up a separate NodeJS server to run 2-lines of script is a pretty big waste of overhead, devops complexity and maintenance (think of spinning up a dev instance every time to run an if-then) -- it's not that hard, but it could be the reason for a 2-day 24-hour marathon debugging exercise in 2 years when you forget about this, or when you hire a junior dev who doesn't know about this and butchers it...